# When it is appropriate to use an html header tag?

Tags: html, header, seo

My question is, is it bad for SEO to use a header tag in a format like the following:

```
H1-page_title-H1                                 H1-side bar-H1
page contents                                    H4-side sub head-H4
                                                 so on here
```

Try to picture the above as my sites "general" layout, leaving out header, navigation, et cetera.

Is it OK to use an h4 for sub headings? Is it inappropriate to use them? Thanks!

Comment: In this [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iR5itZlq8sk) Matt Cutts explains that as long as you don't do crazy things with your headers tags, you should be fine. You can browse related videos, but I don't think it is a problem.

Comment: The title mentions “an html header tag” but the text does not explain what it means; apparently not the proposed `header` tag. Questions about “appropriate” or “proper” are usually not constructive, and comments about “SEO effects” tend to be speculative. The structure is clearly illogical (4th level heading after 1st level heading), and no reason is given why this is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question... here are a couple resources I just found.

http://www.portent.com/blog/seo/5-ways-to-use-headings-for-seo.htm

http://www.searchenginejournal.com/seo-checklist-using-page-headings-correctly/7723/

http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/headers/

Comment: This is not an answer to any of the question asked, just a list of URLs.

Comment: @Jukka - I spent time investigating his question and provided information that helped him solve his problem... therefore, it is an answer. Stop trolling.

Comment: I don't understand how this was off topic, but @viscro thanks again.